# Is it possible to use Dependency Injection/IoC on an ASP.NET MVC FilterAttribute?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, filterattribute

I've got a simple custom `FilterAttribute` which I use decorate various `ActionMethods`.

eg.

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get)]
[MyCustomFilter]
public ActionResult Bar(...)
{ ... }
```

Now, I wish to add some logging to this CustomFilter Action .. so being a good boy, I'm using `DI/IoC` ... and as such wish to use this pattern for my custom `FilterAttribute`.

So if i have the following...

```
ILoggingService
```

and wish to add this my custom `FilterAttribute` .. i'm not sure how. Like, it's easy for me to do the following...

```
public class MyCustomFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute
{
    public MyCustomFilterAttribute(ILoggingService loggingService)
    { ... }
}
```

But the compiler errors saying the attribute which decorates my `ActionMethod` (listed above...) **requires 1 arg** .. so i'm just not sure what to do :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got property injection working with [Ninject](http://github.com/ninject/ninject) and the [Ninject.Web.MVC](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc).

As long as you've got the controller factory from Ninject.Web.MVC, it's rather simple.

E.g.

```
public class EventExistsAttribute : FilterAttribute, IActionFilter
{
    [Inject]
    public IEventRepository EventRepo { private get; set; }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        //Do something else if you so wish...
    }
}
```

It has the drawback of essentially having a 'hidden' dependency, so to say... but there ain't much you can do about that.

HTHs,
Charles

Answer (score 2):

You need to write your own IActionInvoker and do property injection. Have a look at [this](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/jimmy_bogard/archive/2010/05/03/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-filters.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+LosTechies+%28LosTechies%29) post by Jimmy Bogard for ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to use dependency injection on a FilterAttribute.  However it not possible to use constructor injection on a FilterAttribute.  This is not a limitation of ASP.NET MVC, it is a common to all .Net code, as [the values passed into an attributes constuctor are limited to simple types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235617/how-to-pass-objects-into-an-attribute-constructor).

```
[MyFilter(ILogger logger)] // this will not compile
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

So the common practice is to make the dependency a *property* of your filter, as in @Charlino's example.  You can then use property injection.  You can use Ninject to decorate the filter property as in @Charlino's example.  Or as suggested by @mrydengren, you can do this in a custom subclass of ControllerActionInvoker.