# Is it possible to determine the type responsible for constructing an attribute in c#

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, attributes

Attribute constructors are called after calling `GetCustomAttributes()` on a type that is decorated with attributes.  Is it possible to determine the calling type from within the constructor.  I would like to do something similar to the following and have it not throw.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myAttributedClassType = typeof(MyAttributedClass);
        var customAttributes = myAttributedClassType.GetCustomAttributes(false)
                                                    .OfType<MyAttribute>();
        if (customAttributes.Any(x => x.CallingType != myAttributedClassType))
        {
            throw new Exception("MyAttribute.CallingType was incorrect.");
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type CallingType { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute()
    {
        // magic to set CallingType goes here
    }
}

[MyAttribute]
class MyAttributedClass { }
```

**UPDATE:**

I know that this can be done easily through named parameters in the constructor

```
[MyAttribute(CallingType = typeof(MyAttributedClass)
```

or a required parameter

```
public MyAttributed(Type callingType)
{
    CallingType = callingType;    // this doesn't qualify as magic ;)
}
```

but was hoping there was a way to avoid it since the type object itself (the value I want) is the caller of `GetCustomAttributes`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235617/how-to-pass-objects-into-an-attribute-constructor you can pass type to the attribute constructor

Comment: No nice ways. You might able to do some things with stack trace / frames, but nothing pretty

Comment: @cheedep I was trying to avoid passing the type in since there may be cases of many of these on a single type, it just looks overly redundant.

Comment: @MarcGravell thanks, that's what I figured.

Comment: you could do it with postsharp (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851365/how-to-inject-an-attribute-using-a-postsharp-attribute) but it uses some compile time magic to do the same thing behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Your magic, not really magic though:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class)]
class MyAttribute : Attribute
{
    public Type CallingType { get; set; }

    public MyAttribute(Type type)
    {
       // heres your magic
       this.CallingType = type;
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
[MyAttribute(typeof(MyClass))]
```

Comment: The downvote makes sense since there's obviously better way to do this: /sarcasm