# CustomAttribute: how to set DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, attributes

I am loooking for an elegant way to set the value of DateTime.Now as value of an Attribute.

I have this code:

```
    [MyValue(DateTime.Now)]
    public DateTime? VertragDatum { get; set; }
```

But I am getting a syntax error and tells me that the Type DateTime is not a valid attribute parameter type. Do you have any idea how to can achieve that?

My implementation:

```
public class MyValueAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string MyValue { get; }

    public MyValueAttribute(DateTime myValue)
    {
        MyValue = myValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: when do you want that value set? on object creation, on type initialization? sounds like an xy problem here.

Comment: Please note, that `DateTime.Now` will be set at *compile time* (e.g. `6 Aug 2019 17:21:05`) and be read at *runtime* (say somewhen at `14 Oct 2019 14:52:47`). Do you really want such behavior?

Comment: Following on with what @dymanoid says, the only thing you can use as a constructor parameter for an attribute is a constant expression.  C# has no constant or literal `DateTime`s (unlike VB).  If it's always `DateTime.Now`, you can set it in the constructor.  But, not only will `DateTime.Now` not work where it is, no DateTime expression will.

Comment: You can potentially create a "fody" weaver to inject the current date-time in as a string or some sort of roslyn based plugin. I suspect that's outside the scope of what users want for this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass objects into an attribute constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235617/how-to-pass-objects-into-an-attribute-constructor)

Answer (score -1):

DateTime isn't a supported type.

As referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/attributes#attribute-parameter-types) valid types are:

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class
>   are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> - One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int,    long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.
> - The type object.
> - The type System.Type.
> - An enum type, provided it has public accessibility and the types in which it is nested (if any) also have public accessibility (Attribute
>     specification).
> - Single-dimensional arrays of the above types.
> - A constructor argument or public field which does not have one of these types, cannot be used as a positional or named    parameter in
>     an attribute specification.

Comment: I think due to the question in general being down voted

Answer (score -2):

[specs](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/spec/attributes.md#attribute-parameter-types) says:

> The types of positional and named parameters for an attribute class
>   are limited to the attribute parameter types, which are:
>
> One of the following types: bool, byte, char, double, float, int,
>   long, sbyte, short, string, uint, ulong, ushort.

Comment: This answer is missing valid parameter types.